How does one find AWS access portal URL in AWS Management Console?
I enabled IAM Identity Center in Amazon AWS console (web one). 
Then I created a few users in IAM Identity Center and even tried to log in them using configured permission sets.
Then I forgot where my AWS access portal URL is in AWS Management Console. 
My browser history do not have records because I tried those users in private mode.
How do I find my AWS access portal URL in AWS Management Console?

Found my AWS access portal URL in IAM Identity Center -> Dashboard (opens by default) -> Settings summary section -> AWS access portal URL
It is described in the official AWS docs (I have found it in SSO part of the docs):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtochangeURL.html
